# SQL Returning Results based on an indirect criteria

Tags: sql

I am very new to sql so I hope this explanation makes sense.

I would like to return sales pries. Find all ID1's based on ID3 when given ID2

My tables looks like this
Table 1             Table 2

```
ID1 Sales       ID1 ID2 ID3
A   10          A   0   #
B   20          B   1   #
C   30          C   2   #
D   40          D   3   *
E   50          E   4   $
F   60          F   5   $
G   70          G   6   #
H   80          H   7   %
I   90          I   8   %
```

Result when looking for ID2 = 0 would be

Results ID2 = 0

```
ID1 Sales
A   10
B   20
C   30
G   70


select ID1,Sales 

from table1 

where ID1 in (select ID1 from table2 where ID3 in ( select ID3 from table2 where ID2 = 0))
```

Thanks Everyone for your help. I managed to get my answer by using the following. Your help is much appreciated, I learned a lot

Comment: Some formatting would make the table structure much easier to read.

Comment: You have two tables, what do each represent and what result are you hoping to find with your query?

Comment: Table one is a sales price table which is coded with a unique number. Table 2 has 3 id types on it. So ID1 is the key, ID2 is the ID I will be given and ID3 is a historical ID which has muliple ID2's associated with it. What I need is, when given ID2 find all ID1's historically associated with ID2 to get historical sales prices. So in the results table. This is the result of ID2 equalling 0

Comment: What queries have you tried so far and what results have they returned?

Comment: I don't even know where to start. I can code this in Excel VBA by storing it in an array, or creating a 3rd table. But with SQL I am struggling to even ask for what I need

Comment: I would start by getting the value of ID3 where ID2 = 0

Comment: I would start by giving tables 1 and 2 understandable names, then understandable column names. Then show your desired results.  Preferablly using something like sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ID1,Sales from table1 where ID1 in(select ID1 from table2 where ID3 in (select ID3 from table where ID2=0))
```

Comment: Except it is incomplete. There are two tables he is trying to join and this neither of them is named [table].

Comment: Thanks, I know this was incomplete but it helped me understand structure a little better and ultimately solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

So you need three pieces of information.

The first is what id3 value are you looking for?

The answer is '#'.

Then you want to get all of the id1 values that have that id3 value.

Finally you want to return a result set of id1 and sales.

```
select -- step 3
  table1.id1
 ,table1.sales
from
  table1 
inner join -- step 2
  table2 
on table1.id1 = table2.id1
inner join (
select
  id3
from
  table2
where
  id2 = 0 ) as subquery -- step 1
on table2.id3 = subquery.id3
```

Comment: Guys thanks very much for your help. I still can't this to work. I'll go buy an sql book and figure it out from there.